# CertificateError: hostname 'www.wdylike.appspot.com' doesn't match

Tags: python, python-3.x, profanity

I am doing the udacity course on learning python. Basically, this project is supposed to check for profanity in a file. We use the website "https://wdylike.appspot.com/?q=" to do this. The website checks for profanity and prints a Boolean value if there is or is not profanity. Unfortunately, they taught the course in python 2.7 while I have python 3.5 and there are some changes. So, I am turning to you. Whenever I run the code below, I get an error. I will show the exact error below the code.

```
import urllib.request as urlr

def read_text():
    quotes = open(r"C:\Users\setup\Documents\Sophomore Year\Math\Code_Help.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    print(text_to_check)
    link = ("https://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q=")
    connection = urlr.urlopen (link + text_to_check)
    output = connection.read()
    print(output)
    connection.close()

read_text()
```

The error is:

```
CertificateError: hostname 'www.wdylike.appspot.com' doesn't match either of '*.appspot-preview.com', '*.appspot.com', '*.thinkwithgoogle.com', '*.withgoogle.com', '*.withyoutube.com', 'appspot-preview.com', 'appspot.com', 'thinkwithgoogle.com', 'withgoogle.com', 'withyoutube.com'
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The file you see in (r"C:\Users\setup\Documents\Sophomore Year\Math\Code_Help.txt") is simply a text file with the word "ass" in it so as to trigger the profanity detector.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like an invalid ssl certificate to me, if you go to the page with your browser does it throw warnings?

Comment: THAT PAGE IS NOT SECURE (very dangerous)

Comment: go to that site in your browser

Comment: Agreed. There's nothing wrong with your code. There's something wrong with that server. It might be as simple as an expired certificate, it might be as bad as someone having compromised the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message `CertificateError: hostname 'www.wdylike.appspot.com' doesn't match either of '*.appspot-preview.com', '*.appspot.com', '*.thinkwithgoogle.com', '*.withgoogle.com', '*.withyoutube.com', 'appspot-preview.com', 'appspot.com', 'thinkwithgoogle.com', 'withgoogle.com', 'withyoutube.com'`

If you read it carefully, you'll see that it's nothing wrong with your code. It simply says that the url (www.wdylike.appspot.com) does not match anything the certificate is valid for. A certificate must match the url. Try with different urls.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was freaking out that I had some part of the code wrong. I will try different urls and see how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: One could say that if 'www.wdylike.appspot.com' DID get approved with that certificate, something is SERIOUSLY wrong.